# How to render server side and switch to ContextAPI in NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, next.js, react-fullstack

I have this Redis + NextJS 13 application that display records and allows the user to modify these records on screen (CRUD). Here is my attempt to handling things the best way possible:

1. NextJS server receives the client request and generates the page by requesting database records.
2. Client receives the page with the data and **stores the server generated data in the ContextAPI** *(because data is accessed globally)*.
3. Whenever a user edits a record, an API call is made to the backend to update the record in the database, and the changes are reflected in the client by modifying the ContextAPI state instead of making another API call to get the newest data.

The problem is, I don't know how to better handle it than getting the records server-side and then storing this data in ContextAPI frontend and then generating the HTML components. This means that I can't generate the HTML server-side, so **it seems I don't get to use NextJS 13 at its full power for this use case**.

Do you see another way of doing this that could make a better use of NextJS 13 ?